# Binary String Surjection

Tags: functions

Is there a surjection from the finite length binary strings $\{0,1\}^*$ to the infinite length binary strings $\{0,1\}^\omega$ with a finite number of 1's?

Thanks!

Comment: A binary string of infinite length with finitely many $1$'s can be truncated at the last $1$.  Or a finite length binary string can be extended by $0$'s.

Answer (score 0):

The set of binary words with finitely many $1$'s is equal to $\{0,1\}^*0^\omega$. Now, the map $f: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*0^\omega$ defined by 
$$
f(u) = \begin{cases}
u10^\omega & \text{if $u \not= \varepsilon$}\\
0^\omega & \text{if $u = \varepsilon$}
\end{cases}
$$ 
is surjective. Note that $f$ is not a bijective, since for instance $f(0) = f(00)$.

If you want a bijection, you could take the function $g: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*0^\omega$ defined as follows:
$$
g(u) = \begin{cases}
u10^\omega & \text{if $u$ contains at least one $1$}\\
0^n10^\omega & \text{if $u = 0^{n+1}$}\\
0^\omega & \text{if $u = \varepsilon$}
\end{cases}
$$